# How to make a bash write to trace.log, trace1.log, etc.?

Tags: bash, logging

I am making a script and would like to write it to another file if that one exists?

```
traceroute google.com > trace.log
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Also, i am a newbie, so an example would be helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=
while true
do
    fname="trace$n.log"
    [ -f "$fname" ] || break
    n=$(($n+1))
done
traceroute google.com >"$fname"
```

The above loops through each potential name in turn, `trace.log`, `trace1.log`, `trace2.log`, etc.  The first time that it finds a name which doesn't exist, it breaks out of the loop and runs your `traceroute` command.

Caveat: This script does not attempt to handle race conditions.  In particular, there is an instant in time after the script checks for the existence of a file but before this script opens that file for writing.  In that instant, another running program could try to create the file.  In the unlikely event that this is a concern for you, a more complex approach would be called for.

Comment: Also, I know this is not the question, but how do I make the file run every hour?

Comment: @user285771 To run something every hour, use `cron`.  You should probably read about cron. Then, run `crontab -e` to edit/create your cron file.  Add a line to it that looks like `5  *  * * *   /path/to/script`.  That will run `script` once an hour at five minutes past the hour.

Comment: I did that, but I still only have 1 log after waiting 2 hours. ?

Comment: @Autospamfighter If you got one, maybe you should just wait a little longer.  Otherwise, try changing the crontab line to `*/4 * * * * /path/to/script >$HOME/script.log 2>&1`.  That does two things.  First the `*/4` part means that it will run the script every four minutes instead of once an hour.  This will reduce the wait time.  Second, the last part, `>>$HOME/script.log 2>&1`, will cause it to save all error messages to the file `script.log` in your home directory.  Hopefully, something in that log file will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I found it out. Check out my new question here: http://superuser.com/questions/789383/script-wont-loop-through-files-like-planned

Comment: @Autospamfighter I looked at the new question.  I suspect that 
ValmikyArquissanda's answer is correct.