# Script won't loop through files like planned

Tags: bash, logging

I got this script that loops through log files, but I changed something and it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=
while true
do
    fname="trace$n.log"
    [ -f "$fname" ] || break
    n=$(($n+1))
done
traceroute google.com >"$fname"
```

Changed to:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=
while true
do
    fname="trace$n.log"
    [ -f "$fname" ] || break
    n=$(($n+1))
done
traceroute google.com >~/Scripts/logs/"$fname"
```

The last line was changed and now it won't work!
Help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Define what you mean by "it won't work" beside being in a different directory now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with "it won't work"?

Note that your `[ -f "$fname" ]` is testing the wrong directory; make it `[ -f ~/Scripts/logs/"$fname" ]`.